# Pyside2 QQuickView has no rootContext?

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication                                      
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView                                          
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl, QObject, Signal, Slot                          

if __name__== "__main__":                                                       

    app = QApplication([])                                                      
    view = QQuickView()                                                         

    url = QUrl("view.qml")                                                      

    view.setSource(url)                                                         

    root = view.rootContext()
```

This gets an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 14, in <module>

root = view.rootContext()
AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtQuick.QQuickView' object has no attribute 'rootContext'
```

It sure looks like it has that in the docs:

[Pyside2 docs for QQuickView](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtQuick/QQuickView.html)

Comment: You are correct, what version of PySide2 are you using? What is your OS? How have you installed PySide2? In linux with PySide2 5.13 it works correctly

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 pyside 2 version '2.0.0~alpha0' (from ROS) .. totally could be an alpha issue.

Comment: PySide2 2.0.0 is an alpha from more than 1 year ago that has many, but many bugs.

Comment: you could try `view.engine().rootContext()` as a work around

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by doing something different. I also ended up using the pip Pyside2 vs the ROS apt Pyside2 package, but that was (mostly) unrelated.

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml                                        
from PySide2.QtCore import (                                                    
    QUrl,                                                                       
    QObject,                                                                    
    Signal,                                                                     
    Slot,                                                                       
    QCoreApplication,                                                           
    Property,                                                                   
)   

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)                                       
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()                                      
    url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('./assets/qml/main.qml')                    
    engine.load(url)                                                            
    app_controller = AppController()                                            
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("app_controller", app_controller)
```

Then for qml, since I don't have a window from the QQuickView I added a window qml parent (main.qml). Note I also have a home.qml I load content into. (Loader is great):

```
import QtQuick 2.5                                                              
import QtQuick.Window 2.1                                                       
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4                                                     
import QtMultimedia 5.6                                                         

Window {                                                                        
    id: mainWindow                                                              
    visible: true                                                               
    width: 640                                                                  
    height: 480                                                                 
    Rectangle{                                                                                                                                                                                              
        width: parent.width                                                     
        height: 30                                                              
        Button{                                                                 
            text: "Home"                                                        
            onClicked: pageLoader.source="home.qml"                             
            x:0                                                                 
            y:0                                                                 
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           
    Rectangle{                                                                   
        width: parent.width                                                      
        height: parent.height - 30                                               
        x:0                                                                      
        y:30                                                                     

        Item{                                                                    
            Loader {                                                             
                id: pageLoader                                                   
                anchors.fill: parent                                             
                source: "home.qml"                                               
            }                                                                    
        }                                                                        
    }                                                                            
}
```